# How to check if two cells have the same value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PSQL to query a database. I'm using two tables (`d_items` and `chartevents`) which are linked using `itemid`.

The following code

```
    select 
      subject_id, hadm_id, icustay_id
    , di.itemid, di.label
    , charttime, storetime
    , value, valuenum, valueuom
    , error, resultstatus
from chartevents ce
inner join d_items di
  on ce.itemid = di.itemid
where subject_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10
and di.itemid in
(
  8368, 51
)
order by subject_id, charttime, itemid)
```

Outputs:

[image: Excel]
(Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7PwR.png)

I  only want to keep the measurements that include both systolic and diastolic BP. So actually, each (unique) charttime has to have both. How do I achieve this?

Comment: your question is not clear  .. show your expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions or `exists`.  So, here is one way:

```
with t as (
      select subject_id, hadm_id, icustay_id,
             di.itemid, di.label,
             charttime, storetime,
             value, valuenum, valueuom,
             error, resultstatus
      from chartevents ce inner join
           d_items di
           on ce.itemid = di.itemid
      where subject_id between 1 and 10 and
            di.itemid in (8368, 51)
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum( (itemid = 51):: int) over (partition by subject_id, charttime) as cnt_51,
             sum( (itemid = 8368):: int) over (partition by subject_id, charttime) as cnt_8368
      from t
     ) t
where cnt_51 > 0 and cnt_8368 > 0
order by subject_id, charttime, itemid;
```

I am using the `itemid` to identify the two measurements.  You might need to use `like` on the `label`.

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer who uses Oracle, but, I think I can provide some concepts to assist you.
Looking at your table, I think table d_items is merely a label to identify the
data with systolic measurements vs. diastolic measurements.  So, we can ignore table
d_items.
I think your goal is to display the systolic BP and the diastolic BP on the same record.
What you want to do is to join table chartevents against itself.  I assume that subject_id
and chartime will define a unique set of records.  Looking at the output columns, it looks
like value and valuenum represent the same data.

Your table join will look something like this:
Select ...  systol.value, diastol.value......
  from chartevents systol
  join chartevents diastol
    on (systol.subject_id = diastol.subject_id
    and systol.charttime = diastol.charttime)
 where ...

I will leave the rest of the work to you to complete the query.